# How to get the first row where value is found using itertuples()

Tags: python-2.7

I am using the code below to get the first row where "value" is found, but I am getting the last row of the file. What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to get the first row?

Suppose my dataframe look like this:

```
Summary no          
This is an analysis         

of some data            
Phone: 452-354-4456         

col1       Value    col2    col3
bac15        job    $16.00  $0.00 
khs         bank    $19.25  $0.00 
jsg         foot    $0.00   $70,000.00 
eyhf        water   $15.00  $0.00 
edf         drink   $15.00  $0.00 


for fname in os.listdir(root_dir):
    file_path = os.path.join(root_dir, fname)
    if fname.endswith(('.csv')):
        df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
        for row in df.itertuples():
            if row == "value":
                print(row)
```

Comment: I think the reason behind this issue is that the line: "if row == "value" is not working, but I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the entire row to the string `"value"`, which will never be true, sine `row` is a tuple of the values in each row of the dataframe.
Rows containing "`value"` can be found using `if "value" in row:` 
rather than `if row == "value":`